# Why the bitmap is empty

Tags: android

I am following the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) to take picture with other app AND with customized SurfaceView.

When take picture with SurfaceView, the picture is taken successfully (I quit my app and saw the result image file does exist in file manager, and the image content is correct.), but the picture cannot show correctly in my app. The ImageView shows nothing.

My code is like this:

```
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    try {
      File file = Utils.getOutputMediaFile(Utils.MediaFileType.Image);
      FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
      os.write(data);
      os.flush();
      os.close();

      final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
      showImage(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken, e=" + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken, e=" + e);
    }

    camera.startPreview();
  }

  private void showImage(Uri imageFileUri) {
    int w = mContentContainer.getWidth();
    int h = mContentContainer.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmp = Utils.loadBitmapFromFile(imageFileUri.getPath(), w, h);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    mStatusTextView.setText("take photo: succcess");
  }

  public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromFile(String filename, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, opt);
    Log.d(TAG, "loadBitmapFromFile, w=" + opt.outWidth + ", h=" + opt.outHeight);

    int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(opt.outWidth / maxWidth);
    int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(opt.outHeight / maxHeight);

    if (widthRatio > 1 || heightRatio > 1) {
      if (widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        opt.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
      } else {
        opt.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
      }
    }

    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, opt);
    Log.d(TAG, "loadBitmapFromFile, bmp=" + bmp);
    return bmp;
  }
```

From log, I saw the width and height is correctly loaded from file, and bmp is not null, but the ImageView is just empty.

Strange is, if my app firstly take a photo and show the photo with showImage() (the ImageView shows photo correctly), then after that, take phone with SurfaceView and show with showImage(), the photo shows correctly. But if directly take phone with SurfaceView and showImage(), the ImageView is empty.

Any comments about why the ImageView is empty? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try (see the `comments`):

```
  private void showImage(Uri imageFileUri) {
    int w = mContentContainer.getWidth();
    int h = mContentContainer.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmp = Utils.loadBitmapFromFile(imageFileUri.getPath(), w, h);
    mImageView.requestLayout(); //try to request the layout first
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    //if its still not working try to call invalidate() method here
    mStatusTextView.setText("take photo: succcess");
  }
```